# Groovy Grape imports aren't resolved by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, groovy-grape

groovy eclipse plugin version: 1.7.5.xx-20101020-1000-e36-release.

```
import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton

@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,2.3.0)')
public class TestClassAnnotation {
    public static String testMethod () {
        return JideSplitButton.class.name
    }
}

new TestClassAnnotation().testMethod()
```

the first line error: Groovy:unable to resolve class com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton

it can run as groovy shell, but the error warning is bore

Answer (score 0):

When I compile this in the editor, I get the same error as I do when I compile or run from the command line:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.jidesoft#jide-oss;[2.2.1,2.3.0): not found]

(and then a very long stack trace)
```

Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: no, it can compile and  run exactly what I need. but the ide waring at the the first line error: Groovy:unable to resolve class com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton.

Comment: my ide is lastest version of STS, and then groovy plugin

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I can't reproduce the behavior that you are seeing.  I'd recommend raising a bug on the issue tracker:  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather late to this question, but I wonder if
 
`@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,2.3.0)')` 
shouldn't be 
`@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,2.3.0]')`

It looks to me like a syntax error where groovy expects to be passed a list.

Comment: Isn't that just a quoted version string, where ")" usually excludes the upper range?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing @Grab right above the import statement. Just like that:

```
 @Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss',version='[2.2.1,2.3.0]') 
 import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton

... your code continues here
```